# Application terminate automatically - react native android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm using react native to develop android app.
And used ignite.

But when I Run my project in android studio to simulate, the program suddenly shut down.

by the error, it's the kind of network(maybe) but I don't know how to fix it.

below is my logcat of my emulator.

thanks

```
W/unknown:ReactNative: The packager does not seem to be running as we got an IOException requesting its status: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8081) after 5000ms
W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
W/unknown:ReconnectingWebSocket: Couldn't connect to "ws://10.0.2.2:8081/message?device=Android%20SDK%20built%20for%20x86%20-%206.0%20-
%20API%2023&app=com.earlierdoctor.hospital6&clientid=DevSupportManagerImpl", will silently retry

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4859 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Did you change the ip and port in dev settings

Comment: @JainZz thank you for your comment. could you tell me which file sets ip and port? cuz I took over this file

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Your packager doesn't seem to be running, try navigating into your project directory and run `react-native start` before trying to run the app.